# Custom UINavigationBar does not honour given height

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom UINavigationBar, called MapNavBar. This class is declared as follows:

```
class MapNavBar: UINavigationBar {

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let landscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height
    if landscape {
        let navBarHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
        return CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: navBarHeight)
    }
    return super.sizeThatFits(size)
}
```

}

The custom navigation bar is assigned to the navigation controller like so:

```
navController.setValue(MapNavBar(), forKeyPath : "navigationBar")
```

Now when the orientation changes to landscape I would like to keep the navigation bar height to the standard (portrait orientation) height of 44.  So in the MapController viewWillLayoutSubviews I do:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    if let navController = ... {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let landscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height
        if landscape {
            let navBarHeight = navController.navigationBar.sizeThatFits(screenSize).height

            // Resize navBar
            navController.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(screenSize.width), height: Int(navBarHeight))
        }
    }
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Despite all efforts, the custom navigation bar height remains at 32 points when in landscape. I have checked and the navigationBar property of the navigation controller is indeed an instance of my custom MapNavBar.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MapNavBar: UINavigationBar {

    let navBarHeight: CGFloat = 64 //44 + 20 Where 20 is for status bar, it is hidden in landscape mode always

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

        let frame = self.frame
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let landscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height
        if landscape {
            return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: navBarHeight)
        }
        return super.sizeThatFits(size)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let landscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height
        if landscape {
            let y = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
            frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y:  y, width: frame.size.width, height: navBarHeight)

            for subview in self.subviews {
                var stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
                if stringFromClass.contains("BarBackground") {
                    subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: navBarHeight)
                    subview.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
                }

                stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
                if stringFromClass.contains("BarContent") {
                    subview.frame = CGRect(x: subview.frame.origin.x, y: 0, width: subview.frame.width, height: navBarHeight)
                    subview.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with auto layout? Will it work nicely with `safeAreaInsets`? (I'm not saying it won't, just wondering.)

Comment: @Sateesh thanks! That seems to do the job. The Bar button items are misaligned though, stuck at the top. Would you know where to use the setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment call for each bar button item so that it is centered vertically on the bar?

Comment: @DonMiguel, can you please share the code for how UIBarButtonItems are created.

Comment: @Sateesh the bar button items are created without any vertical position adjustment as their default placement is correct in portrait. However, when in landscape I try and update their position within layoutSubviews of the navigation bar: if let navigationItem = self.topItem {
                    if let leftItems = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems {
                        for item: UIBarButtonItem in leftItems {
                            item.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(navBarHeight/2, for: .default)
                        }
                    }